# Field theory on a lattice, what is this?

Tags: field-theory, lattice-model

I only have the training of undergraduate quantum mechanics and solid state physics. For me, field theory is defined on a continuous space.

So, what does lattice field theory mean? Is it similar to the tight binding model in solid state physics?

In solid state physics, we know there are many lattice effects which are lattice artifacts. Are there similar issues in lattice field theory?

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with solving differential equations with finite difference methods?  Lattice field theory is just an approximate method of solving 3-D field theory problems by replacing the continuum with a finite lattice of points. The 3-D aspect makes the problem more complicated than a simple finite difference (1-D) solution, but conceptually they are equivalent.

In classical continuum mechanics there are similar methods that are called finite element analysis. Here, however, the elements are considered to be actual pieces of a physical object so a different name was required. In condensed matter physics there is a physical lattice (where atoms are located) but there could also be lattice field theory (of phonons, for example).  In lattice field theory (as in finite difference methods) the points are chosen arbitrarily with mathematical convenience as the only factor considered.

Comment: I would also include cases where the lattice is physical, such as in condensed matter physics, as being examples of lattice field theory.

Comment: @StephenPowell I agree and have edited to include that aspect.